# Time format in datagrid

Tags: php, sql, oracle, timestamp, sysdate

I have a question...how can I calculate the difference between sysdate and a column named "creation time"? 
Here is a part of SQL (i;m usin oracle database):

```
$g->select_command = "select c.case_id as \"NGM ID\",   
       s.NE_PRIORITAET as \"NE Prio\",
       case substr(s.NE_ID, 2,1)
         when '1' then 'Nord'
         when '2' then 'Nord' 
         when '3' then 'Ost'
         when '4' then 'Ost'
         when '5' then 'Mitte'
         when '6' then 'West'
         when '7' then 'Süd'
         when '8' then 'Mitte'
         when '9' then 'Süd'
         else          'Error'
       end as \"Region\",         
       c.STATUS_NGM as \"NGM Status\",
       s.AUFTRAG as \"Auftrag\",
       s.NE_ID as \"NE ID\",
       s.STATUS as \"SAP Status\",
       substr(to_char(to_timestamp(Sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 8) as \"Diff Beginn Sap Ende\",
       case trim(s.KATEGORIE)
         when '1' then 'INSLA'
         when '2' then 'OUTSLA'
         else          s.KATEGORIE
       end as \"SLA\",
       c.CREATION_TIME as \"NGM Creation Time\",
```

Comment: What type does the `creation time` column have?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the difference between two dates in days you can simple use the subtraction operation, like this:

```
with s as (
  select to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') CREATION_TIME from dual
)
select sysdate - s.CREATION_TIME
  from s

DIFF
--------------
226.6314236111
```

Comment: creation time it's date. I will try your solution!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle there are two different datatypes when subtracting dates and timestamps.
Distance between two DATE datatypes is a number, where a unit stands for day.
Distance between two TIMESTAMP datatypes is an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. It's a datatype prepared for visualization in days:hours:minutes:seconds format.

```
select sysdate-to_date('2014.08.15','YYYY.MM.DD') as date_type
     , systimestamp - to_timestamp('2014.08.15','YYYY.MM.DD') as ts_type
     , dump(sysdate-to_date('2014.08.15','YYYY.MM.DD')) as date_datatype
     , dump(systimestamp - to_timestamp('2014.08.15','YYYY.MM.DD')) as ts_datatype
  from dual;

 DATE_TYPE
----------
TS_TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATE_DATATYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TS_DATATYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
,972719907
+000000000 23:20:43.608000
Typ=14 Len=8: 0,0,0,0,75,72,1,0
Typ=190 Len=24: 0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,43,0,0,0,0,88,61,36,10,0,0,0
```